# Python - Get a date dd.mm.yyyy from any string bsp.("aa;l sd20.10.1980adgf")

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

How should I do this?
Should I use Regex? If so, how? 
And in the example below I want to know if this string(tr.get_text()) contains a date in the format dd.mm.yyyy. One of its outputs could look like this ('\nMi\n11.10.201708:1509:45HS H "Ulrich Santner" (NTEG230E)Abhaltungfix')

```
for page in pages:
    for tr in page.find_all('tr', {'class': 'coTableR'}):
        print(tr.get_text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex.

```
import re
s = '\nMi\n11.10.201708:1509:45HS H "Ulrich Santner" (NTEG230E)Abhaltungfix'
m = re.search(r"(?P<date>\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})", s)
if m:
    print(m.group('date'))
```

**Output:**

```
11.10.2017
```